# Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Login failed for user 'userdb'

Tags: c#, sql-server, docker, .net-core

I'm using C# and ASP.NET Core 6. I need to connect a Docker container of my app, with the container of SQL Server.

> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Login failed for user 'userdb'.
> Error Number:18456,State:1,Class:14

When I use the local version of my code it connects and saves the new data on the database of the container, I'm getting the error when I try to communicate the two docker images.

I have this `ConnectionString` using credentials I created, the same I use to log in using SSMS

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "mydb": "Server=ams;Database=mydb;User ID=userdb; Password=P@ssword!;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;Trusted_Connection=False;TrustServerCertificate=True"
  }
```

And I'm using this docker-compose.yml to run both containers

```
version: '3.9'
services: 
  server:
    image: "mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2022-latest"
    container_name: dbc
    ports: 
        - "1433:1433" 
    environment:
        ACCEPT_EULA: "Y"
        userdb_PASSWORD: "P@ssword!"

  ams:
    image: ams:latest
    ports:
        - "7049:80"
        - "7048:443"
    environment:
      ASPNETCORE_URLS: "https://+;http://+"
      ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT: "7048"
      ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT: Development
    volumes:
        - ${APPDATA}\microsoft\UserSecrets\:/root/.microsoft/usersecrets
        - ${USERPROFILE}\.aspnet\https:/root/.aspnet/https/
```

The hole response is this:

```
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Login failed for user 'userdb'.
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.CompleteLogin(Boolean enlistOK)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, Boolean withFailover)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, TimeoutTimer timeout)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling, String accessToken, DbConnectionPool pool)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, SqlConnectionOverrides overrides)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open(SqlConnectionOverrides overrides)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerConnection.OpenDbConnection(Boolean errorsExpected)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenInternal(Boolean errorsExpected)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.Open(Boolean errorsExpected)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.RelationalDatabaseFacadeExtensions.<>c.<OpenConnection>b__22_0(DatabaseFacade database)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ExecutionStrategyExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass12_0`2.<Execute>b__0(DbContext _, TState s)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.Execute[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`3 operation, Func`3 verifySucceeded)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ExecutionStrategyExtensions.Execute[TState,TResult](IExecutionStrategy strategy, TState state, Func`2 operation, Func`2 verifySucceeded)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.RelationalDatabaseFacadeExtensions.OpenConnection(DatabaseFacade databaseFacade)
   at AuthMs.Controllers.AuthController.Register(CredentialDto request) in /src/AuthMs/Controllers/AuthController.cs:line 43
   at lambda_method5(Closure , Object )
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.AwaitableObjectResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>g__Awaited|12_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, ValueTask`1 actionResultValueTask)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|20_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
ClientConnectionId:8132639a-17e1-45e0-8ffb-803a815913c0
Error Number:18456,State:1,Class:14
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: There's not a lot happening in your Docker compose with regards to configuring the `mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server` image. Why do you expect the login to succeed when you haven't created either the custom login nor the database indicated in the connection string? Also `Server=ams;` should probably be `Server=dbc;`

Comment: SQL Server does not send back all the info for login failures to the client, but it keeps them in its log. Check the logs for the specific failure. Most likely, you have not configured the server to accept SQL Auth, but that's just a guess.

Comment: I created the custom login using SSMS, and the database works fine with the local code. I followed a tutorial for the docker-compose so I'm not sure if I should add something else.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning, I tried changing to > Server=dbc; but I keep getting the same error.

Comment: @JPAlioto, I checked and it's enabled the SQL Auth, and about the logs I actually don't understand much about it.

Comment: _I created the custom login using SSMS, and the database works fine with the local code._ You could not have done that with this particular Docker instance - since the required `MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD` environment variable has not been supplied to the container there is no way you could have logged in to it to do those things. Perhaps you created the database, login and user on a different one?

Comment: If you have a read through the [`mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server` image documentation](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-mssql-server) you might notice this section, _See this example of [using an entrypoint.sh and setup.sql scripts to create a database](https://github.com/microsoft/mssql-docker/tree/master/linux/preview/examples/mssql-customize)_ and which can be extended to create server-level logins, database-level users, permissions, schema, etc..

Comment: Review the SQL Server logs you will see much more information about why the user is being denied access. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/view-the-sql-server-error-log-sql-server-management-studio?view=sql-server-ver16